# Power Rule for group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Is it true that, for $x$ integer
$$(ab)^x=b^xa^x?$$
I believe the fact $$(ab)^x=(a^xb^x)$$ is not true in general, right?

Comment: What sort of thing is $x$ here?

Comment: I intend x to be any real number. Does certain value of $x$ make the second statement true? Any relation with $2p$, $p$ being prime?

Comment: Any *real* number? Your question is nonsense then.

Comment: @user1709828: What is the meaning of the power of an elemnt in a group? Do we assume it **a real number** or an integer?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I meant integer. Sorry.

Comment: @user1709828: One can write $a^x$ to mean $x^{-1}ax$ when $a$ and $x$ and both group elements (this is standard notation). *Then* what you said is true.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume $x$ is an integer. To find out the answer, pick two elements of the group $$Q_8=\langle i,j,k\mid i^2=j^2=k^2=ijk\rangle=\{i,j,k,+1,-1,-i,-j,-k\}$$ in which $$ij=k,ji=-k,~~~~jk=i,kj=-i,~~~~ki=j,jk=-i$$and then examine the identities you noted for some integer $x$.

Comment: Fun avatar, Babak, +1!

Comment: @julien: Thanks Julien. I love Jim Carrey. The avatar is he in the MASK. ;-)

Comment: Nicely put! $\quad+\quad$

Answer (score 3):

If you *fix a particular value of $x$*, though, there might be nonabelian groups where
$$
(a b)^x = a^x b^x\tag{pow}
$$
for all $a, b \in G$. For instance if $x$ is an odd prime, there exists a non-abelian group of order $x^3$ and exponent $x$, so (pow) holds in $G$ for such an $x$.

Answer (score 2):

For $x=1$, the equality $(ab)^x=b^xa^x$ becomes $ab=ba$, that is $a$ and $b$ commute: it can not be true in general. However, the equality holds (for $x \in \mathbb{Z}$) when $a$ and $b$ commute (use induction).